# while() loop keeps iterating unexpectedly

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop

```
program
int main()
{
    int a=0xabcd;
    char *p=&a;
    while(p)
    {
        if(*p=='c')
        {
            printf("i got %c\n",*p);
            return; 
        }
        p++;
    }

}
```

1)why i got always an answer like **"i got c"**.
2)no matter how many times i execute this program, why i got **%c as c**.
3)replace c character with any character, no matter ,why we got such a character that what we put in if condition?.

```
if(*p=='z') or if(*p=='t') or ....
```

4)can anybody explain what was the reason?

Comment: [Undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `while(p)` looks weird.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: ... because of pointer arithmetic outside the bounds of an array.

Comment: Your program won't stop scanning memory until it either finds the character you are looking for or it crashes.  So I'm not sure what you expected the program to do, crash?

Comment: `char *p=&a;` is ill-formed so the behaviour of this whole program is undefined. You probably meant `char *p = (char *)&a;`. If your compiler didn't report this then use compiler switches to activate its conforming mode.

Comment: This looks like a question to test understanding of C code with many traps in it.

Comment: Why do you have return; in your if statement?! You are in the function main which returns int value, so it can't return nothing (void). If ypu want to stop while, use break instead.

Comment: if you didn't get c then how did the if is executed, then how did the string got printed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the nice answer by Mr. **@Lundin**, just to clarify the logic for the *print* s,

> 1)why i got always an answer like "i got c".

Because, you wrote the code to do so. Keeping away the programmatic errors, if you check the logic, you wrote the code so that the `printf()` will only be executed if `*p` has a value equal to `c`. So, no wonder, all the time `printf()` (if encountered) will print

```
i got c
```

Next,

> 2) no matter how many times i execute this program, why i got %c as c.

Correct. Same reason as above.

> 3)replace c character with any character, no matter ,why we got such a character that what we put in if condition?.

Your `printf()` will only be executed *if* the `if` condition satisfies. So whatever character you'll use in your `if` condition, `printf()` will print only that character only.

Comment: Why repeating an explanation that has already been given twice ?

Comment: It is actually a small wonder if the program prints "i got c" before crashing. Oh, the wondrous things made possible by invoking undefined behavior!

Comment: @chmike wow!! Sorry, but is that the reason for downvote? Thanks, btw, for taking your time to post the comment. :-)

Comment: @chmike It's not exactly *the same* explanation. Different views on the same topic are useful, because you never know which way of explaining the problem someone will find helpful, being fit to their knowledge, language, ways of reasoning, etc.

Answer (score 5):

- `int a=0xabcd` on a 32 bit machine will give you `0x0000abcd`. If you try to read the contents of this integer as a character, you'll either get 0x00 or 0xcd, depending on endianess. Neither is a printable ASCII character. This doesn't make any sense.
- `while(p)` means "while p points at an address which is not zero". This doesn't make any sense. Because of this, you continue to loop and read random memory cells outside the allocated integer. Anything can happen. If you are lucky, the program will crash.

To sum it up, it appears you don't quite know what you are doing...

Comment: OP's `while (p)` probably should be `while (*p)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat And how exactly does that make more sense?

Comment: It would make more sense if `char a = "abcd"; ` and `char *p = a;`.

Answer (score 2):

1) You get `i got c` because your program has a pointer `p` that points on each bytes of 0xabcd in sequence and beyond ! At some point, the pointer will point on the byte 0x63 which is 'c'. Since this is the `if` condition, the  print statement prints the char pointed by *p* and you see the message `i got c`.

2) because of the if condition that execute the print statement only if the byte pointed by *p* is 0x63 thus 'c'. This is why you always see the same message. Note however that it only works if there is a byte with value 0x63 somewhere in memory.

3) You would write it like this to display other characters.

```
if((*p=='z') || (*p=='t') || ....)
```

4) see above answers.

Comment: I think it is far more likely that the program will crash & burn before finding a binary 'c'. But maybe the OP is one of them DOS programmers...

Comment: This depends on the OS.

Comment: It doesn't matter if there is such a byte or not, the loop causes UB so the compiler can do anything. It could optimize the code to remove the loop and output the string without even reading any memory.

Comment: @Matt McNabb That would be surprising.

Comment: [Here](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/161) is some discussion. Other than the fact that it's UB anyway for reading beyond allocated memory; the compiler can assume there are no infinite loops with no output. Since this loop only has one exit point then that must be reached.  (`while(p)` can be deduced to never be false unless UB has occurred)

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to know what you're doing.

Closest working exaple would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2] = {0x0a0b0c0d, 0};
    char *p = (char *) a;

    while (*p)
    {
        if (*p == 0x0c)
        {
            printf("i got c\n");
            return 0; 
        }
        p++;
    }

}
```

Or another better solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 0x0a0b0c0d;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (int); i++)
    {
        if(((char *) &a)[i] == 0x0c)
        {
            printf("i got c\n");
            return 0; 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you know that this is what he wants to do ?

Comment: @chmike I can't imagine what else OP's program could be intended to do.

Comment: I can't imagine what the OP could possibly have intended.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  `char *a = "abcd"; char *p = a; while (*p) { if (*p == 'c') ... `